# for loop in if else conditions in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to script the following task.

I have a file in which node name and ips are updated, I have to make each file of those nodes which are not in our required directory and those are in updated file
and also editing their name.

I have to give input from bottom to upward means from last line to upward and my script will run from bottom to upward according to my need means those entries which are missing in my required directory.

I use if else condition and have to place for loop to do my task until it equals.

My script is

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

giosdir=$(find /usr/local/example-dir  -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)

lbdir=$(more /root/scripts/servers/new/example.txt |wc -l)

count=$(($lbdir-$giosdir))

lait2=1

l2=$(awk '{print $3}' < /root/scripts/servers/new/example.txt | tail -$lait2)

lait=1

newip=$(awk '{print $1}' < /root/scripts/servers/new/example.txt | tail -$lait)

if [ $nagiosdir -eq $lbdir ] ; then

    echo " Nothing to do "

else

    if [ $giosdir -lt $lbdir ] ; then


       for((i=0;i<count;i++));do

       {

            cd /usr/local/

            cp example-Node-2.txt   $l2.txt

            sed -i 's/10.10.0.1/'$newip'/' $l2.txt

            sed -i 's/examole-Node-2.txt/'$l2'/' $l2.txt

            echo " Node is added successfull"

            lait2++;

            lait++;           

       }

    fi

fi
```

I am getting this error:

```
line 43: syntax error near unexpected token `fi' 
line 43: `         fi  '
```

Description of my script

1. first line is taking input from a directory that how many number of files are there.
2. This line is taking input from a file that how many lines are there
3. subtracting the numbers and the value would be an integer
4. declaring variable valu which is use in next line
5. this line taking input from a file and cut the 3rd column in which nodes name are save
6. also a variable
7. taking an ip as an input from a file
8. if condition

What is the syntax for a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to mark the end of your `for` loop with the keyword `done`.

You also can't do arithmetic like `lait1++`. You have to do something like

```
lait1=$(($lait1+1))
```

Here's [more info](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) on doing arithmetic operations in Bash shell scripts.

Comment: yeah...but know it is showing
line 40: lait++: command not found
it has to add + 1

Comment: @HassanSohail: Updated my answer.

Comment: lait1=$(($lait1+1))    
why you use this ?

Comment: tail -$lait2

I have to add 1 after running loop once

Comment: @HassanSohail: That's how you increment a variable in Bash.

Comment: ok actually i am facing other issue due this my task is doing fail